# get wordpress author link outside theme

Tags: wordpress

i want get author meta's outside the wordpress in html pages

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 3,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'category' => 2,
    'suppress_filters' => true
);

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );



  $contpost=0;
foreach($recent_posts as $post) :
      ?>
```

i use this codes to get post information but i cant get author information such as name and link 
i try to get this information by this functions

```
the_author(), get_the_author(), get_the_author_id(), the_author_link(), get_the_author_link(), the_author_meta(), get_the_author_meta(), the_author_posts(), get_the_author_posts(), the_author_posts_link(), get_author_posts_url(), get_the_modified_author(), the_modified_author(), wp_dropdown_users(), wp_list_authors()
```

also i cant again 
please help me

Comment: what you mean with `outside the wordpress`?

Comment: i design a html page outside the word press for main page of my site now i want get recent post in this page i can get post title post link anythings about post except author name and link

Comment: where is your `html page` is located? and how do you trying to call it( request url )?

Comment: my html file is in root page and my wordpress in /wordpress/ folder and i call with <?php require '../wordpress/wp-load.php';?>

Comment: actually i can read anything from wordpress except author information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Codex, most of the functions you list will only work in "the loop"; the rest require the author ID to be provided as a parameter.
A quick check of Codex indicates these might work in your foreach loop.

```
foreach($recent_posts as $post) :
  $author_id = $post["post_author"];
  $author_url = get_author_posts_url( $author_id);
  $author_displayname = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);
  // render html using above vars as required
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to post id then you can get author details

```
$author_id = $post->post_author;
$author_name = get_the_author_meta('nickname',$authot_id);
```

Comment: thank you i test this before this code's just get me a short string " class="posted-by__author""